# Iterating through an array of Objects - Javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
// Hi, I am having following array of data
const MyCorp = [{
    firstName: "ABC Corp",
    ownShareholders: true,
    percentageOwnership: 50,
    shareholders: [{
        firstName: "XYZ Corp",
        percentageOwnership: 50,
        ownShareholders: false,
        shareholders: []
      },
      {
        firstName: "DEF Corp",
        ownShareholders: true,
        percentageOwnership: 60,
        shareholders: [{
            firstName: "SAY Corp",
            percentageOwnership: 50,
            ownShareholders: false,
            shareholders: []
          },
          {
            firstName: "No Corp",
            ownShareholders: false,
            percentageOwnership: 50,
            shareholders: []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    firstName: "Test Corp",
    ownShareholders: false,
    shareholders: [],
    percentageOwnership: 50
  }
]

// A trying to iterate over the data to get below output

// MyCorp share value = 50+ 50 == 100 (50 is from ABC Corp and  50 is of Test Corp)
// ABC Corp share value = 50 + 60 ===110(50 is from XYZ Corp and  60 is of DEF Corp)
// DEF Corp Share value = 50+ 50 === 100(50 is from SAY Corp and 50 is of No Corp)
// Output can be a object or array

// What I did to achieve this 

const ShareArray = (shareholders) => {
  const something = [];
  shareholders.forEach((shareholder) => {
    if (shareholder.ownShareholders === true) {
      something.push(shareholder.shareholders);
    }
  });
  return validateSharePercentage(something[0])
};

const validateSharePercentage = shareholders => {
  let value = 0;
  shareholders.forEach(shareholder => {
    value += shareholder.percentageOwnership;
  });
  return value;
};
const somevalue = validateSharePercentage(MyCorp);
console.log(somevalue);
const arrayValues = ShareArray(MyCorp);
console.log(arrayValues);
```

I am getting 100 and 110 but not sure how to iterate through all child items and get total share value of individual company

Child shareholders might grow as per user need - seems I need to implement recursive function but I have failed in implementing that too
Please Help...
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added MyCorp to the same structure(firstName, ownShareholders, percentageOwnership, shareholders)

```js
const MyCorp = [{
    firstName: 'MyCorp',
    ownShareholders: true,
    shareholders: [{
        firstName: 'ABC Corp',
        ownShareholders: true,
        percentageOwnership: 50,
        shareholders: [{
            firstName: 'XYZ Corp',
            percentageOwnership: 50,
            ownShareholders: false,
            shareholders: []
        },
        {
            firstName: 'DEF Corp',
            ownShareholders: true,
            percentageOwnership: 60,
            shareholders: [{
                firstName: 'SAY Corp',
                percentageOwnership: 50,
                ownShareholders: false,
                shareholders: []
            },
            {
                firstName: 'No Corp',
                ownShareholders: false,
                percentageOwnership: 50,
                shareholders: []
            }
            ]
        }
        ]
    },
    {
        firstName: 'Test Corp',
        ownShareholders: false,
        shareholders: [],
        percentageOwnership: 50
    }
    ]
}];

const getShareValue = (comp) => comp.reduce((result, current) => result += current.percentageOwnership, 0);

const calc = (comp) => {
    let result = {};
    comp.forEach((current) => {
        if (current.ownShareholders) {
            result = Object.assign(result, calc(current.shareholders));
            result[current.firstName] = getShareValue(current.shareholders);
        }
    });

    return result;
};

console.log(calc(MyCorp));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could start by putting the `MyCorp` array in a new array with an object with `firstName` and `shareholders` like the rest of the data so you can use a recursive algorithm.

Then it's just a matter of collecting `percentageOwnership` of each shareholder and calling the function recursively on the `shareholders` arrays.

**Example**

```js
const MyCorp = [
  {
    firstName: "ABC Corp",
    ownShareholders: true,
    percentageOwnership: 50,
    shareholders: [
      {
        firstName: "XYZ Corp",
        percentageOwnership: 50,
        ownShareholders: false,
        shareholders: []
      },
      {
        firstName: "DEF Corp",
        ownShareholders: true,
        percentageOwnership: 60,
        shareholders: [
          {
            firstName: "SAY Corp",
            percentageOwnership: 50,
            ownShareholders: false,
            shareholders: []
          },
          {
            firstName: "No Corp",
            ownShareholders: false,
            percentageOwnership: 50,
            shareholders: []
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    firstName: "Test Corp",
    ownShareholders: false,
    shareholders: [],
    percentageOwnership: 50
  }
];

const data = [
  {
    firstName: "MyCorp",
    shareholders: MyCorp
  }
];

const result = data.reduce(function getPercentageOwnership(result, element) {
  const { firstName } = element;

  if (element.shareholders.length !== 0) {
    result[firstName] = 0;
  }
  element.shareholders.forEach(shareholder => {
    result[firstName] += shareholder.percentageOwnership;
    getPercentageOwnership(result, shareholder);
  });

  return result;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```